# DXA - Tridion Reference Implementation Publishing

Tags: content-delivery, cme, 2013-sp1, dxa

I've installed DXA based on [Angel Puntero's video tutorial](https://vimeo.com/106436179).

I successfully imported via the PowerShell the reference implementation `.\import.ps1` and installed the `Install WebApplication.ps1` on the same Windows 2012 Server and configured a new website for it in IIS..

I can see the publications within the TCM; however, I think I have the incorrect paths within my `cd_deployer_config` or setup my publication target with the incorrect credentials - because when I publish out the 'Home' SG it fails within the pub que on `Transporting`

[image]
[image]

So I think all I need to change are 2 location paths similar to an example below  where ##NAME## are referenced and then add in the correct `\Tridion\config\cd_licenses.xml` location path, since I sourced this file off an Apache Tomcat deployer.

I've viewed a great configuration example from Nuno [here](http://code.google.com/p/kickstart-tridion-environment/source/browse/CreateAnEnvironmentForMe/CreateAnEnvironmentForMe/ConfigSamples/preview-webservice/cd_deployer_conf.xml) and compared the file against the updated paths I am referencing on the Windows Server (instead of the Tomcat path where I originally sourced this file from) and created my own `\Tridion\stri\incoming` directory, referenced the license path - but I still cannot get the site to publish out successfully.

```
<!-- Configure the Queue locations the deployer checks for incoming deployment packages -->
<Queue>
<Location Path="c:\tridion\##NAME##\incoming" WindowSize="20" Workers="10" Cleanup="true" Interval="2s"/></Queue>
<!--<Location Path="c:\tridion\work\http" WindowSize="10" Workers="10" Cleanup="true" Interval="30s"/> -->
<HTTPSReceiver MaxSize="10000000" Location="c:\tridion\##NAME##\incoming" InProcessDeploy="true"/>
<!--Specifies the location of the license file.-->
<License Location="c:/Program Files (x86)/Tridion/config/cd_licenses.xml"/>
```

And if the issue is not within config file, possibly I do not have the correct credentials set up on my `Publication Target` within the TCM..

Where does the name and password on the publication target below derive from? I placed in the full username and password of the Tridion Content Manager `MTSUser` account..

[image]

Could anyone who set this up properly kindly let me know if the questions above are the reason of the failed on `Transporting` issue I have?

Or have any insight to what I am doing wrong with the DXA import, install and setup?

---

## Updated

Here is the Tridion Event Log:

```
6/22/2015 2:29:52 PM <6180> Updating the publish transaction with the list of processed items
6/22/2015 2:29:53 PM <6180> Saving the transport package.
6/22/2015 2:29:53 PM <6180> Sending tranport package for transaction [tcm:0-15031-66560] with deploy control [Commit] to transport service.
6/22/2015 2:29:56 PM <3196> Transport service response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TransportSummaries>
<TransportSummary referenceId="tcm:0-15031-66560" start="2015-06-22T10:29:56.503-04:00" state="Ready for transport">
    <Processing>
        <Context topic="Content Delivery">
            <IsRollbackOnFailure>false</IsRollbackOnFailure>
        </Context>
        <Step href="simple" type="Prepare transport" start="2015-06-22T10:29:56.503-04:00" state="Ready for transport">
            <RemoteEndpoint connector="HTTPS" id="gGI6kIVDuYKRN+y1B2jq3A==" name="HTTPUpload" start="2015-06-22T10:29:56.503-04:00" state="Ready for transport" windowSize="0"/>
        </Step>
        <Step href="simple" type="Transporting" state="None">
            <RemoteEndpoint connector="HTTPS" id="gGI6kIVDuYKRN+y1B2jq3A==" name="HTTPUpload" state="None" windowSize="0"/>
        </Step>
        <Step href="simple" type="Deployment preparation" state="None">
            <RemoteEndpoint connector="HTTPS" id="gGI6kIVDuYKRN+y1B2jq3A==" name="HTTPUpload" state="None" windowSize="0"/>
        </Step>
        <Step href="simple" type="Deploying" state="None">
            <RemoteEndpoint connector="HTTPS" id="gGI6kIVDuYKRN+y1B2jq3A==" name="HTTPUpload" state="None" windowSize="0"/>
        </Step>
        <Step href="simple" type="Deployment committing" state="None">
            <RemoteEndpoint connector="HTTPS" id="gGI6kIVDuYKRN+y1B2jq3A==" name="HTTPUpload" state="None" windowSize="0"/>
        </Step>
    </Processing>
</TransportSummary>
```

```
6/22/2015 2:29:56 PM <3196> Receiving deployment feedback for publish transaction [tcm:0-15031-66560] with status: ReadyForTransport
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180> Sending information to transport service took: 00:00:03.8703926.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180> Transport service reported state [ReadyForTransport] for Publish Transaction [tcm:0-15031-66560] with response: <TransportSummary referenceId="tcm:0-15031-66560" start="2015-06-22T10:29:56.503-04:00" state="Ready for transport"><Processing><Context topic="Content Delivery"><IsRollbackOnFailure>false</IsRollbackOnFailure></Context><Step end="2015-06-22T10:29:57.315-04:00" href="simple" type="Prepare transport" start="2015-06-22T10:29:56.503-04:00" state="Success"><RemoteEndpoint connector="HTTPS" end="2015-06-22T10:29:57.315-04:00" id="gGI6kIVDuYKRN+y1B2jq3A==" name="HTTPUpload" start="2015-06-22T10:29:56.503-04:00" state="Success" windowSize="20" /></Step><Step href="simple" type="Transporting" state="Ready for transport"><RemoteEndpoint connector="HTTPS" id="gGI6kIVDuYKRN+y1B2jq3A==" name="HTTPUpload" state="Ready for transport" windowSize="20" /></Step><Step href="simple" type="Deployment preparation" state="None"><RemoteEndpoint connector="HTTPS" id="gGI6kIVDuYKRN+y1B2jq3A==" name="HTTPUpload" state="None" windowSize="20" /></Step><Step href="simple" type="Deploying" state="None"><RemoteEndpoint connector="HTTPS" id="gGI6kIVDuYKRN+y1B2jq3A==" name="HTTPUpload" state="None" windowSize="20" /></Step><Step href="simple" type="Deployment committing" state="None"><RemoteEndpoint connector="HTTPS" id="gGI6kIVDuYKRN+y1B2jq3A==" name="HTTPUpload" state="None" windowSize="20" /></Step></Processing></TransportSummary>
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180> Handling Publish Transaction [tcm:0-15031-66560] took: 00:00:57.5949696
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180> Cache statistics: SimpleCache: 19 Regions, 325 Objects, 3731 Hits, 314 Misses
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'Component': 62 Objects, 243 Hits, 62 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'PublishTransaction': 3 Objects, 6 Hits, 1 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'PublicationTarget': 1 Objects, 28 Hits, 1 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'StructureGroup': 13 Objects, 51 Hits, 13 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'Publication': 1 Objects, 83 Hits, 1 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'Page': 26 Objects, 52 Hits, 26 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'PageTemplate': 8 Objects, 49 Hits, 8 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'TemplateBuildingBlock': 17 Objects, 493 Hits, 17 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'ComponentTemplate': 43 Objects, 196 Hits, 43 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'WebDavUrlMapping': 8 Objects, 7 Hits, 8 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'Schema': 39 Objects, 1192 Hits, 39 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'TridionWebSchema': 27 Objects, 683 Hits, 27 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'XmlSchemaCache': 27 Objects, 0 Hits, 27 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'Folder': 22 Objects, 405 Hits, 22 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'Category': 5 Objects, 0 Hits, 5 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'KeywordTitleMapping': 10 Objects, 35 Hits, 10 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'Keyword': 10 Objects, 56 Hits, 0 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'MultimediaType': 3 Objects, 152 Hits, 3 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <6180>   Region 'Tdse': 0 Objects, 0 Hits, 1 Misses.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <364> Deleting queue message: 15449 from PublishQueue.
6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM <3196> Transport service response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TransportSummaries>
<TransportSummary end="2015-06-22T10:29:57.456-04:00" referenceId="tcm:0-15031-66560" start="2015-06-22T10:29:56.503-04:00" state="Failed">
    <Processing>
        <Context topic="Content Delivery">
            <IsRollbackOnFailure>false</IsRollbackOnFailure>
        </Context>
        <Step end="2015-06-22T10:29:57.315-04:00" href="simple" type="Prepare transport" start="2015-06-22T10:29:56.503-04:00" state="Success">
            <RemoteEndpoint connector="HTTPS" end="2015-06-22T10:29:57.315-04:00" id="gGI6kIVDuYKRN+y1B2jq3A==" name="HTTPUpload" start="2015-06-22T10:29:56.503-04:00" state="Success" windowSize="0"/>
        </Step>
        <Step end="2015-06-22T10:29:57.456-04:00" href="simple" type="Transporting" start="2015-06-22T10:29:57.315-04:00" state="Failed">
            <RemoteEndpoint connector="HTTPS" end="2015-06-22T10:29:57.456-04:00" id="gGI6kIVDuYKRN+y1B2jq3A==" name="HTTPUpload" start="2015-06-22T10:29:57.315-04:00" state="Failed" windowSize="0">
                <Message>Transport failed: Could not transport tcm_0-15031-66560.Content.zip using HTTPS, cause: Internal Server Error</Message>
            </RemoteEndpoint>
        </Step>
        <Step href="simple" type="Deployment preparation" state="None">
            <RemoteEndpoint connector="HTTPS" id="gGI6kIVDuYKRN+y1B2jq3A==" name="HTTPUpload" state="None" windowSize="0"/>
        </Step>
        <Step href="simple" type="Deploying" state="None">
            <RemoteEndpoint connector="HTTPS" id="gGI6kIVDuYKRN+y1B2jq3A==" name="HTTPUpload" state="None" windowSize="0"/>
        </Step>
        <Step href="simple" type="Deployment committing" state="None">
            <RemoteEndpoint connector="HTTPS" id="gGI6kIVDuYKRN+y1B2jq3A==" name="HTTPUpload" state="None" windowSize="0"/>
        </Step>
    </Processing>
</TransportSummary>
```

```
6/22/2015 2:29:58 PM <3196> Receiving deployment feedback for publish transaction [tcm:0-15031-66560] with status: Failed
```

---

## Updated 2

[image]

**Warning**

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
  <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" />
  <EventID Qualifiers="32768">1309</EventID>
  <Level>3</Level>
  <Task>3</Task>
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-06-22T14:29:57.000000000Z" />
  <EventRecordID>14292</EventRecordID>
  <Channel>Application</Channel>
  <Computer>xxx.xxx.xxxx.com</Computer>
  <Security />
</System>
<EventData>
  <Data>3004</Data>
  <Data>Post size exceeded allowed limits.</Data>
  <Data>6/22/2015 10:29:57 AM</Data>
  <Data>6/22/2015 2:29:57 PM</Data>
  <Data>e7e1edbe910c4c12ab731c07a700d017</Data>
  <Data>7</Data>
  <Data>1</Data>
  <Data>0</Data>
  <Data>/LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT-1-130794569936281174</Data>
  <Data>Full</Data>
  <Data>/</Data>
  <Data>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\HTTPUpload_Live\</Data>
  <Data>ServerName</Data>
  <Data />
  <Data>10236</Data>
  <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
  <Data>IIS APPPOOL\HTTPUpload_Live</Data>
  <Data>HttpException</Data>
  <Data>Maximum request length exceeded. at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent() at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent() at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() at System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureForm() at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm() at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull) at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)</Data>
  <Data>http://localhost:81/HTTPUpload.aspx</Data>
  <Data>/HTTPUpload.aspx</Data>
  <Data>127.0.0.1</Data>
  <Data />
  <Data>False</Data>
  <Data />
  <Data>IIS APPPOOL\HTTPUpload_Live</Data>
  <Data>7</Data>
  <Data>IIS APPPOOL\HTTPUpload_Live</Data>
  <Data>False</Data>
  <Data>at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent() at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent() at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() at System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureForm() at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm() at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull) at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Could you look in the Tridion Event Log to find the actual error that happens during the 'transporting' step? That would help narrow down what the issue is...

Comment: @PeterKjaer - I have updated the question with the Tridion Event Log

Comment: Try opening the HTTP Upload URL (http://localhost:81/HTTPUpload.aspx) in your browser, to see if you get any errors.

Comment: Also, since the error is an "internal server error" during the upload, it should show up as a warning from ASP.NET within the Application event log (in Event Viewer). Please have a look at that and see if there are any clues as to what went wrong.

Comment: @PeterKjaer - Yes. I can view HTTPUpload successfully. I did see 4 warnings in the Tridion App Event Log within Event Viewer - also updated within the question.

Comment: @PeterKjaer - the tcm:123-4394 - is the Core component from the `Module Configuration` schema. 100 Master > Building Blocks > Modules  > Core > Admin

Comment: You can ignore those warnings. You need the ones from ASP.NET in the Application event log, since the error happens when HTTPUpload.aspx is called.

Comment: @PeterKjaer - `IIS APPPOOL` - max request length exceeded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems your problem is related to package size since I see errors in your logs corresponding to that. We faced a similar issue with the package size. To fix that you need to set the below attributes in your deployer web.config under `HTTPUPLOAD`:

1. Under `system.web` section add the below:

   `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="Sizeyouwantinbytes" />`
2. Under `<security>` add the below in the `requestfiltering` attribute

   `<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="Sizeyouwantinbytes" />`

   by default requestLimits is set to appoximately 30 MBs

   MS documentation on both these attributes and their usage [RequestLimits](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits)
   [httpruntime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Perfect! I just took a web.config from here and it is working correclty through the `transporting` process. http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2011/07/manually-configuring-tridion-2011-net.html

Comment: As a general comment this is likely to be seen more in the future (as higher-res images are supported/expected in DXA) - an extra +1 for the post's :)